# jsTree removes hash from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm trying to use a JSON generated jsTree to navigate a directory structure. Currently I'm binding a select_node event to get the path of the selected node as a string and then set the `location.hash` to that path. This part actually works fine. My problem is that immediately after my select_node event completes something else removes the hash from the url entirely which obviously breaks the browser history and sends the user back to the "index" page. Here's my current code. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
$('#projects').jstree({
  core: {
    animation: 0
  },
  plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
  themes: {
    theme: "gm",
    dots: false
  },
  json_data: {
    ajax: {
      url: '/json/projects',
    },
    progressive_render: true
  }
}).bind('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
  var path = '#/' + $(this).jstree('get_path', data.rslt.obj, false).join('/')
  window.location.hash = path
})
```

Comment: I' like to know this also. I'll have the same problem tomorrow at work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem code is this:

```
var path = '/' + $(this).jstree('get_path', data.rslt.obj, false).join('/')
```

You can probably use

```
var path = '/' + $(this).jstree('get_path', data.rslt.obj, false).join('/') + location.hash
```

to ensure that the hash remains.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my example. `path` is actually supposed to be what `window.location.hash` is set to which actually happens fine. The problem is that immediately afterwards something else in jstree reverts it to nothing.

Comment: can you use location.search instead? maybe jstree requires the use of location.hash

Comment: I'm using ajax to pull the directory listing based on the hash so no, I cannot. I either need to stop jstree from messing with the hash automatically (which does absolutely nothing with my current setup since there are no actual links) or find some other way to make each item link to its path.